# How to properly pass variables in an array from a form using Javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I run the code below it works fine

```
<script>

var key_values =[79, 129, 183, 128, 66];
const secret_keys = new Uint8Array(key_values);
console.log(secret_keys);

//Uint8Array(64) [ 79, 129, 183, 128, 66 ]

</script>
```

**Here is my issue:**

when I pass the **key_values** variable into an arrays from form inputs. it does not display any value in the console.

This is what it displayed in the console **Uint8Array [0]** instead of **Uint8Array(64) [ 79, 129, 183, 128, 66 ]**

**here is the code.**

```
<script>
            $(function () {
                $('#save').click(function () {
                    
// inputted form values 79, 129, 183, 128, 66

var key_values = $('#my_keys').val();

const secret_keys = new Uint8Array([key_values]);
console.log(secret_keys);

//Uint8Array [0]



    });
            });
</script>
<input type="text" id="my_keys" value="79, 129, 183, 128, 66">

                    <input type="button" id="save" value="save" />
```

Comment: <input> values are just text, you have to parse the text into an array. When you do `[key_values]` you end up with `["79, 129, 183, 128, 66"]`, i.e. an array with a string as the only element. You can try `var key_values = JSON.parse("[" + $('#my_keys').val() + "]")` but you should probably wrap that in a try/catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the string as an array before passing it to the constructor or just `split` by comma to get an array.

```
const secret_keys = new Uint8Array(key_values.split(","));
```